# Why is it called "Rust"?

Tags: naming, rust

Why is the Rust programming language called "Rust"?

Is there anything known about who named it, and why? (I am having a hard time coming up with a positive association).

Comment: A theory I've occasionally seen hinted at on Reddit/IRC/mailing-list is that the goal of the language is to use tried-and-true techniques (i.e. rusty), rather than implement cutting edge experimental features. No idea of the truth of it though.

Comment: "Rust" makes me, personally, think "close to the metal", suggesting good performance (but I try not to think of it as eating away at the silicon :-)

Answer (score 70):

There is [a thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/27jvdt/internet_archaeology_the_definitive_endall_source/) that claims the answer.

TL;DR: Rust is named after [a fungus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_%28fungus%29) that is robust, distributed, and parallel.

It is also a subsequence of "robust".

---

Found another [interesting quote](http://tim.dreamwidth.org/1784423.html):

> Also, calling Rust a research language is funny to me because -- as its name reflects -- we've tried hard to avoid incorporating new technology into it. We haven't always succeeded at failing to be novel, but we have a rule of thumb of not including any ideas in the language that are new as of the past ten years of programming language research. The field of programming language is full of old technology that hasn't been put to use in solving problems that it's exactly suited for. The goals with Rust were to avoid reinventing wheels, and see what the past had to teach us. I can't blame anyone for thinking Rust is a research language, though, since it is being developed by Mozilla Research.

So this alludes to "exclusively relying on old technology and shunning the new".

Again, I get the "old" implication of "rust", but still cannot get over the "will eventually corrode to junk metal" association.

Comment: interesting substring reference right there!

Comment: Naming a programming language after a pathogen does have its unfortunate aspects.

Comment: Rust cannot corrode.

Answer (score 34):

It's by analogy to web browser architecture.  The user-interface parts of mozilla are often called "chrome", because they're supposed to be shiny (this was the case even before the chrome browser came along).  And in Firefox, a lot of chrome code is implemented in javascript.

Rust, on the other hand, is intended for implementing the guts of the browser; the non-chrome parts.  The name makes me think of big metal gears meshing together deep in the bowels of some giant machine.

Comment: +1. That makes sense. But still makes me think of "big metal gears about to corrode and break".

Comment: Do you happen to have any links/references for this?

Comment: This is consistent with Rust's logo.